# Exchanging data between django apps in the same project

Tags: django

I would like to exchange data between two django apps that are coming from a single big app that due to the increasing size and functionalities we decided to split.

Specifically I need to retrive only a string in one app from the other. Litterally a 10 character string.

The only thing that I found at the moment that satisfies me, since I would like to avoid import stuff from the other app (to me it seems not a clean way to do it, in the other case please change my mind), is making an http request from one app to the other.
Anyway I found it overkill.

Is there a clean way to achive this without using http request or imports?

Comment: If the code producing the 10 character string can be decoupled from the app I would put it in an `utils` directory at the same level as the two apps (`utils` doesn't have to be an app, though).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean constant app configuration data, that lives in the project `settings.py` adnd doesn't change except at a server re-start

```
from django.conf import settings
```

[more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/)

It's possible to make an `import` fail soft, if you just want to handle the case where the other app is not installed. For example

```
try:
    from other_app.models import Foo
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from .models import Foo_Stub as Foo
```

(obviously you can get as sophisticated as you want with your stub models and other methods that aren't available from the other app).